# SwiftUI best practices: should View have a constant to singletons and should they be passed in the Environment?

Tags: swiftui, singleton, swiftui-environment

In Xcode 12 template for a SwiftUI project using Core Data, Apple provides the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct CoreDataApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the persistenceController is a singleton.

What's the difference with following code, where the singleton is initialized and passed at the same time? Why do we use a constant for the singleton?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct CoreDataApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, are there any advantages to providing this singleton to the environment? Couldn't we just use `PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext` directly in subviews?

I'm asking because I have few services singletons in my app but I don't want to initialize them from the main `App` but in subviews.

Comment: Actually no difference here, in first case just better readability.

Comment: Thanks! What about the use of Environment for singleton objects?

Comment: Environment is a just a way to inject value into view hierarchy, no matter which kind of value: primitive, struct, or pointer to shared object (as in this case).